# Creating a modal with 2 buttons that execute functions, but I want to gray out the buttons that are bound with a function that returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I'm creating a game as a way to practice JS, and over the course of the game a modal will pop up offering two options. Depending on the state of the game, one option might be unavailable.

I built a "set up modal" function that takes in the name of the modal, the two choices, and the two functions that become bound to the buttons. The functions are defined elsewhere and are then passed into the buttons. If both functions are valid (don't return `false`) I can click either button in the modal and the functions executes. This currently works fine.

However, the functions return `false` if they can't be executed. Without explaining the details of the game, think of it like you can't have more than $5, so the function `gainMoney(x)` will return `false` if you already have $5.

I want `modalDef()` to be able to check to see if `function1` and `function2` are `false`, and if they are, it grays out the button and doesn't set the event listener. If `not false`, the button becomes a valid with an event bound to it. The entire setup works except for when I have a function that returns `false`.

I've been testing with a function that always returns `false`, and here's what happens:

In the below version, I use a simple `not` boolean to check the function. After I click the button for the function, the action executes (returning a `false` value), and THEN the button turns gray (`opacity 0.3`), and the modal doesn't disappear.

```
function modalDef(action, option1, option2, function1, function2){

//set the text of the modal

  $("#modal-action").text(action);
  $("#modal-choice1").text(option1);
  $("#modal-choice2").text(option2);

  //set the functions of each button using the function inputs

  $("#modal-choice1").one("click",function(){

//this is the line I need help with
    if(!function1()){
      $("#modal-choice1").css("opacity","0.3");
    }
    else{
      function1();
      modalToggle("hide");
    }

  });

  $("#modal-choice2").one("click",function(){
    if(!function2()){
      $("#modal-choice2").css("opacity","0.3");
    }
    else{
      function2();
      modalToggle("hide");
    }

  });

}
```

In the below version, i use `.toString == false` to check if the function is `false` (saw that somewhere on the interwebs). When I click the button, the function executes (returning a `false` value) and the modal disappears, basically as if the entire function was valid.

```
function modalDef(action, option1, option2, function1, function2){

//set the text of the modal

  $("#modal-action").text(action);
  $("#modal-choice1").text(option1);
  $("#modal-choice2").text(option2);

  //set the functions of each button using the function inputs

  $("#modal-choice1").one("click",function(){

//this is the line I need help with
    if(function1.toString == false){
      $("#modal-choice1").css("opacity","0.3");
    }
    else{
      function1();
      modalToggle("hide");
    }

  });

  $("#modal-choice2").one("click",function(){
    if(function2() == false){
      $("#modal-choice2").css("opacity","0.3");
    }
    else{
      function2();
      modalToggle("hide");
    }

  });

}
```

What is the correct way to do an `if/else` where the `if` checks to see if a function returns `false`?

EDIT: I'll add how I apply this, and again, this works except for the checking for `false` to lower the opacity:

```
function x(){previousBuiltFunction(input)}
function y(){previousBuiltFunction(input)}

modalDef("Choices","Choice 1", "Choice 2", x, y}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!function(parameter)) {
}
```

The function returns false, this way you check if the function is the word "false"

Comment: I posted a bit more on how I apply the modalDef function. As it stands, I can't pass parameters to the function inside of the if statement. And I don't even need to for it to work when the function is valid.

Comment: Just invoke the function, by adding "()" at the end of the function name. You then can invert the return value of that function by adding a "!" infront, so the if is true, when the function is false.

Comment: Isn't that what I have up there in my first version? if ( !function1() ) {   }. Maybe I'm failing to see a minute difference.

Comment: Because it is called in the onClick. Invoke the function on loading the page, and then hide if needed.